# What is the correct why to get EclipseLink JPA query.getResultList() results in the cache?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

When I use EclipseLink JPA query.getResultList() it doesn't store the results in the cache so when I call merge the first call does a select all then update for each object.

What's the correct all to get query results in the cache?

I'm thinking do the query then call EntityManager find for each result - but seems wrong. Obviously I can't call find first as I don't know the object id.

Basically I want to cache all the data in-memory (in the cache) and have updates as quick as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink caches every object returned by getResultList() in the shared (L2) cache by default.

If you are not getting caching, then you have mis-configured something.

Please include your code, configuration, and SQL log.

Are you using Spring? (see http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/200321/)

Ensure you have not disabled the shared cache, or configured refreshing.

How many object are you reading, and how long is it from the query to the merge?  If you are reading a lot of objects, you may need to increase the cache size (default is 100), or change the cache type.

See, http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching